# Installing QGIS for Mac?

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

Could someone help me install QGIS 1.7.3 for a Mac and possibly give step by step instructions?

I have already installed QGIS 1.8 for a Mac, however I have heard that the 1.7.3 will run smoother without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have installed the newest version I think you already have these dependencies: (still no harm in making sure)

```
http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Complete-1.10.dmg
http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GSL_Framework-1.16-1.dmg
```

Afterwards, install qgis:

[QGIS 1.7.3 for Leopard](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/qgis/Qgis-1.7.0-3-Leopard.dmg)

[QGIS 1.7.3 for Snow](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/qgis/Qgis-1.7.0-3-Snow.dmg)

Do you need help in the installation of a .dmg file?